# Replace characters in JSON Keys

Tags: json, regex, salesforce, apex

I have very odd question that involves JSON Returned to me by D&B Matching API.
The Problem I am facing is that there are this very odd formatted keys

```
ReliabilityText":{  
    "@DNBCodeValue":9092,
    "$":"Actual"
}
```

I want to replace the '@' and '$' characters with a simple text.

I thought of solution using Regular expression, but I couldn't find any solution so far.

Thing that I forgot to mention is that I am using Salesforce APEX to run the code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "...I couldn't find any solution so far" in regards to RegEx.  You should be able to do `for (var key in json) {json[key] = json[key].replace(/@/, "simpletext")}`

Comment: Is there anything that works for you? Can you replace a simple char like `a` with anything?

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/dwTbTM/9) this worked like a charm. For dollar sign I have used apex's string.replace('"$" :', '"value" :').